# Getting 'net/url: invalid control character in URL' error when my start up script runs with VM instance

Tags: python, google-compute-engine

I have a created a Python virtual environment on a VM instance.

The idea is that when the VM instance is restarted a start up script should run that activates the virtual environment and then runs a python script that creates a simple file.

The script runs fine if I ssh into the VM, activate the virtual environment and run `python3 test.py`.

However, its not working when the start up script runs.

When i check `sudo journalctl -u google-startup-scripts.service` I am seeing the following error:

`python3 /home/will_charles/tools/test.py: net/url: invalid control character in URL`

This is the file structure in my VM instance:

```
\tools
    \venv
    \test.py
```

I tried the following start up script first:

```
cd /home/will_charles/tools
source venv/bin/activate
python3 test.py
```

and got the above error

I then tried:

```
cd /home/will_charles/tools
source venv/bin/activate
python3 /home/will_charles/tools/test.py
```

but got the same error.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I stupidly set 'start up script url' in the custom meta data.
Not 'start up script'. Hence why I was getting the invalid URL error!